# Id variable for CSS style

Tags: php, html, css

I have the next php code about a foreach loop, where $d->ID is variable:

```
echo '<div id="tabla_'.$d->ID.'" style="display:none">';
echo '<input id="tab-1_'.$d->ID.'" type="radio" name="tab-group'.$d->ID.'" checked="checked"/>
<label for="tab-1_'.$d->ID.'">Tab 1</label>
<input id="tab-2_'.$d->ID.'" type="radio" name="tab-group'.$d->ID.'" />
<label for="tab-2_'.$d->ID.'">Tab2 2</label>
<div id="content_'.$d->ID.'">       
<div id="content-1_'.$d->ID.'">';   
echo 'Hello world 1</div>
<div id="content-2_'.$d->ID.'">Hello world 2!</div></div></div><br>';
```

Now, I have Css style with the next code (This work fine!):

```
div[id^=tabla_] {
margin: 40px auto;
width: 100%;  /* Ancho del contenedor */
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

div[id^=tabla_] input {
height: 32px;
visibility: hidden;
}

div[id^=tabla_] label {
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 15px;  /* Tamaño del texto de las pestañas */
line-height: 40px;
height: 40px;
padding: 0 20px;
display: block;
color: #888;  /* Color del texto de las pestañas */
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
background: #eee;  /* Fondo de las pestañas */
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

but now, I have the next code that not work fine :(

```
div[id^=tabla_] input[id^=tab-1_]:checked ~ [id^=content_] [id^=content-1_],
div[id^=tabla_] input[id^=tab-2_]:checked ~ [id^=content_] [id^=content-2_]{
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
-moz-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
-o-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
-ms-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
}
```

Some idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: _"that not work fine"_ meens what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set a opacity for the (unchecked) `[id^=content_] [id^=content-1_]`, so it allways will be equal to `1` (as this is the browsers default).

Add an

```
[id^=content_] [id^=content-1_], 
[id^=content_] [id^=content-2_] { opacity: 0; }
```

to hide those by default. The `opacity: 1;` in the `:checked`-rule will then show them.

```css
div[id^=tabla_] {
margin: 40px auto;
width: 100%;  /* Ancho del contenedor */
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

div[id^=tabla_] input {
height: 32px;
visibility: hidden;
}

div[id^=tabla_] label {
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 15px;  /* Tamaño del texto de las pestañas */
line-height: 40px;
height: 40px;
padding: 0 20px;
display: block;
color: #888;  /* Color del texto de las pestañas */
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
background: #eee;  /* Fondo de las pestañas */
margin-right: 5px;
}

[id^=content_] [id^=content-1_], 
[id^=content_] [id^=content-2_] { opacity: 0; }


div[id^=tabla_] input[id^=tab-1_]:checked ~ [id^=content_] [id^=content-1_],
div[id^=tabla_] input[id^=tab-2_]:checked ~ [id^=content_] [id^=content-2_]{
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
-moz-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
-o-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
-ms-transition: all ease-out 0.2s 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabla_6">
    <input id="tab-1_6" type="radio" name="tab-group6" checked="checked"/>
    <label for="tab-1_6">Tab 1</label>
    <input id="tab-2_6" type="radio" name="tab-group6" />
    <label for="tab-2_6">Tab2 2</label>
    <div id="content_6">       
        <div id="content-1_6">Hello world 1</div>
        <div id="content-2_6">Hello world 2!</div>
    </div>
</div><br>
```

Comment: PS. Please learn how to create a **minimal** example. If your problem is with CSS, provide the/some HTML and not the PHP-code creating it.